# How to replace a variable containing a string by the string itself?

Tags: regex, r

I have a variable with lots of value, one of its value is like 'Blamo BSM258 Clem on/o' and i want to replace it by 'BSM'.
In some words, I want to replace with 'BSM' every value of my variable containing 'BSM'.

I've tried using

```
  sub("(BSM)", "BSM", data$variable)
```

or

```
  data$variable[grep("(BSM)", data$variable)]<-"BSM"
```

but it doesn't work. (it makes 'NA' values)

Comment: Your second attempt seem to work fine for me even with NAs. Can you provide some example data where it failed?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
gsub('BSM', '"BSM"', 'Blamo BSM258 Clem on/o')
```

Comment: Does this really work? The output for me was `"Blamo \"BSM\"258 Clem on/o"`, which is the original string with escaped quotes.

Comment: I also get 
"Blamo \"BSM\"258 Clem on/o"

Comment: from your question it's indeed what you want, to insert " around BSM ? (beware that the display on RGui introduces /)

Comment: i just wanted to replace Blamo BSM258 Clem on/o by BSM

Answer (score 0):

Using sub or gsub only replaces the patterns in the string, so you are just replacing "BSM" with "BSM" not the whole string. But the second example, with `grep` should work. If you are looking for "BSM" in the string, you do not need the parenthesis around it in the grep command, just pass `data$variable[grep("BSM", data$variable)]<-"BSM"` and everything should be done properly.

What is the structure of `data`? Is it a list or a dataframe? If it is a list, then the `$` might not be properly indexing, which could be causing the NA values.

Comment: It is a dataframe, but the variable is read in terms of factors... I do not know how to prevent it.   Here is my warning message:`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grep("[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]BSM[[:digit:]]",  :   invalid factor level, NA generated.